# SetValue webdriver having 2 duplicated outputs

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver

IM TRYING TO DO

```
await browser.setValue('APU')
```

but intead of input APU to the box i have

```
APUAPU
```

Is anyone know why it outputs 2 times to the box